# How to add decimal points in slider and tooltip cursor using jquery

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slider

I have a price range slider.Currently the values are displaying as $400 and in tooltip cursor its 400. but now i want to display the values as $400.00 and in tooltip its should be 400.00. My slider changes its value on click, slide and both plus and minus button clicks.

This is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#bootstrap-slider").slider();
  jQuery("#bootstrap-slider").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    jQuery("#sliderValue").text(slideEvt.value);
  });

  jQuery('.slider').on("click", function() {
    var newvalue = jQuery('.tooltip-inner').text();
    jQuery("#sliderValue").text(newvalue);
  });

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.btn-overflow').click(function(){
      jQuery(this).parents('.entry-content').toggleClass('asd');
    });
    jQuery(window).trigger('scroll');

});

  function addSliderPrice(){
    var price=parseInt(jQuery( "#bootstrap-slider" ).slider('getValue'));
    price=price+200;
    if(price<=500000){
      jQuery( "#bootstrap-slider" ).slider('setValue', price);
      jQuery('#sliderValue').text(price);
    }
    else{
      jQuery( "#bootstrap-slider" ).slider('setValue', 500000);
      jQuery('#sliderValue').text(500000);
    }
 }
 function reduceSliderPrice(){
    var price=parseInt(jQuery( "#bootstrap-slider" ).slider('getValue'));
    price=price-200;
     if(price>400){
        jQuery( "#bootstrap-slider" ).slider('setValue', price);
        jQuery('#sliderValue').text(price);
      }
      else{
         jQuery( "#bootstrap-slider" ).slider('setValue', 400);
          jQuery('#sliderValue').text(400);
      }
 }
```

How can i achieve this view.Can anyone shed some light

Comment: If you just want to change the display value, did you try just changing the text, e.g. change `jQuery('#sliderValue').text(price);` to `jQuery('#sliderValue').text(""+price+".00");` ?

Comment: @fluffykitten i tried this and it displays decimal points for click slide and button press. but i also need to display the same in mouse tooltip

Comment: Did you also change the code where you set the tooltip? I don't see that code in your question so I can't advise where to change it.

Comment: @FluffyKitten we dont kmow how the tooltip is set. its written in min.js file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number.prototype.toFixed()` to format a number to fixed-point notation. Note that this will return a string representation of the number, therefore you should just use it to print the values in the tooltip.

```
(400).toFixed(2);
// "400.00"
```